# Kong manager too many redirects

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kong

Hi I am attempting to install Kong Gateway in Kubernetes (still using the nginx ingress controller), however I get a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error when I attempt to access the manager page using the FQDN (configured in the ingress). I am using LetsEncrypt to provision the TLS certs. I can port forward to the services and things work (as expected) but I can not visit the FQDN. Any help would be much appreciated!

These are the values I am using when installing the Helm chart: [repo](https://github.com/mkm29/kong)

**UPDATE**: I changed the URLs and added some annotations to the ingress specs and things are loading now (minus the enterprise only features, as to be expected as I am not using a valid license)